# Android Kotlin: onTextChanged not being triggered for EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I am creating an `EditText` box with line numbers on the side. To achieve this, I have code in the `onTextChanged` method of the `addTextChangedListener` that updates the line numbers for the `EditText`. For some reason however, the `onTextChanged` event never seems to fire when I type in the `EditText`, as the `println` statement is not being activated.

Below is my XML code:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:columnCount="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linenumber"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_style"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="18dp"></TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textbox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:ems="5"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="" />
</GridLayout>
```

Below is my Kotlin code:

```
var textbox1: EditText = findViewById(R.id.textbox);
var lineNumber: TextView = findViewById(R.id.linenumber);

// Add the line numbers or remove the line numbers based on the user's input
textbox1.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        // Retrieve the number of lines in the user's input
        var lines:Int = lineNumber.getLineCount()
        var linesText:String = "";

        // Loop through the lines
        for (i in 1..lines) {
            linesText = linesText + "\n" + i;
        }

        println("linesText = " + linesText)
        // Update the line numbers
        lineNumber.setText(linesText);
    }
})
```

Comment: It's working fine .

Comment: seems ok.. very basic, can you try to debug and see if it enters the listener?

Comment: Where did you call `textbox1.addTextChangedListener`?

Comment: share the code where you are calling this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the bug and I apologize for not including the line of code in my post where the bug was:

I had the following extra line of code that reset the listener after I initialized the listener:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can spot is:

```
var lines:Int = lineNumber.getLineCount()
```

Shouldn't this be:

```
var lines : Int = textbox1.getLineCount()
```

Also your listener in this instance should be added in onCreate() or onResume().

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody lands here, `android:textAllCaps="true"` in EditText prevented for some reason onTextChanged from being called in my project.